# The toISOString method is returning the year with a zero in front

Tags: javascript, date, toisostring

this function:

```
 handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value,
      displayName: (this.state.firstName.substring(0,2)) + (this.state.lastName.substring(0,2)),
      orderNo: (this.props.children.length + 1).toString(),
      sortBirthDate: this.state.birthDate ? new Date(this.state.birthDate).toISOString() :this.state.birthDate ,
      userId: "8e1d8d"
    });
  }
```

returns everything correctly, except sortBirthDate:

```
birthDate: "09/21/2014"
displayName: "dsda"
firstName: "ds"
lastName: "da"
orderNo: "5"
sortBirthDate: "0201-09-21T05:50:36.000Z"
```

I have tried removing the zero using the substring method, but the year returned is only 3 digits.

does anyone see what I am missing here?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a console log on this.state.birthDate

Comment: You might want to fix the content of `this.state.birthDate` instead of trying to "fix" the result with string manipulations.

Comment: you can see in the return the value of this.state.birthDate.  It is fine and is what is expected.

Comment: If the year really is `201` then what's the problem? The ISO format is defined as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Comment: @Andreas the year that was input is 2014, see birthDate in the return object

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code to reproduce the issue should be posted in the question, preferably as a runnable snippet. At it stands, the issue can't be explained or reproduced so is unlikely to help anyone.

Comment: @RobG I am a new user.  This is one of the first questions I have ever posted.  If there is direction you can offer other than just recommending this gets close, I would be appreciative of that.  I am still have this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @reinhal—the issue is that the code you've posted doesn't produce the result you say you're getting. That doesn't mean you aren't getting the erroneous result, just that until we can see the code that generates the result, we can't help, nor is the question likely to help anyone else. E.g. what does *setState* do? What is the initial value of *state.birthDate*? etc. Reduce the code to a **minimal** example that reproduces the error and add it to the question. That exercise alone may be sufficient for you to discover the source of the problem. :-)

Comment: @RobG yeah, all of that makes sense.  I am trying to step it back.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with setState being async.

Here is what works:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value}, () => {
      this.state.displayName = (this.state.firstName.substring(0,2)) + (this.state.lastName.substring(0,2));
      this.state.orderNo = (this.props.children.length + 1).toString();
      this.state.sortBirthDate = this.state.birthDate ? new Date(this.state.birthDate).toISOString() :this.state.birthDate;
      this.state.userId = "8e1d8d";
    });
  }
```